# Depmod - unresolved symbols in rt73 module

Tags: networking, wireless, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to install a linux driver for my wireless network card (D-Link DWL-G510) on my Red Hat Linux 7.1 machine with a 2.4.37.9 kernel. I downloaded the serial monkey driver from the [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rt2400/) site and was able to successfully compile the module. However, whenever I do a "make install", the make script executes a "depmod -a" command which then complains with the message: "Unresolved symbols in /lib/modules/2.4.37.9/extra/rt73.o".

I then executed a "depmod -e" command to show unresolved symbols and it indicates the following information:

request_firmware_Rsmp_38ce5074
release_firmware_Rsmp_33934162

I did a grep on the above information and it showed no source files making reference to it. I searched for it on google and it returned no results. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason - it was missing the firmware_class module. I had to rebuild kernel modules with the experimental feature CONFIG_FW_LOADER as a module which is found under **Library routines\Hotplug firmware loading support**. After loading the firmware_class module, the rt73 module loaded successfully also.